# Linux - add creation Date or DateTime in the name of the file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filenames, redhat

I have a file on a Linux server which is created automatically.
I would like to create a script which will automatically rename the file after it is created on the server, so it will add date or datetime information

For example:

```
filename.pdf --->210807filename.pdf
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
mv filename.pdf $(date +"%y%m%d")filename.pdf
```

Here is the manpage of date where you can find the different output formats: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/date1.html

If you like to rename all the files with a pattern using a script, you could do something like this:

```
for file in $(ls -1 filename???.pdf); do
    mv $file $(date +"%y%m%d")$file
done
```

This will find all the files with a name like `filename???.pdf` (??? is a wildcard for 3 characters) and add the timestamp in front of their names.

Comment: I wonder how many people turn their head to see what you look like :D +1

Comment: You don't have to turn your head, this is how I look like (-:

Comment: Hi Mathias, thank you for your response it works I will accept answer. May I please add just additional question? My file name has dynamic name for example filename007.pdf ; filename112.pdf etc... Can I cover that use case also with your solution? (numbers are different each day)